# What is SMS Agent Host?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, windows-service

What is SMS Agent Host service (CcmExec)? I have failed to
find this information (e.g. there is no Wikipedia entry) -
besides for information in some error cases on how to
restart this service for dependent software. (The best I 
could find was: "ccmexec.exe is a part of the Microsoft SMS 
operating system service. This service calls upon another 
service, the SMS Agent Host. This program is important for 
the stable and secure running of your computer and should 
not be terminated." and SMS = Systems Management Server)

What purpose does it serve and why would it hold on to
directory handles? E.g. may it scan the entire disk on
behalf of some other service?

Is SMS Agent Host service specific to Windows Server
2003/Windows XP x64?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As you mentioned, this is the agent for Microsoft SMS. SMS can be used to collect inventory, apply patches, deploy software, etc. This is not something that is specific to Server 2003/Windows XP x64. This shouldn't be on a machine unless you have SMS deployed. You can stop the service if it's killing a machine, it just won't report back.

The newer versions of SMS are called System Center Configuration Manager.

Answer (score 1):

Well said rorr,

Give this a look. It explains more about SMS/SCCM

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Center_Configuration_Manager